# Projecting 3D point to 2D image coordinates

Tags: 3d, camera, projection

I am trying to replicate the projections of a 3D point to 2D using the pinhole camera model and the formula $x = K * [R|-RC] * X$, where $x = s\begin{bmatrix}
u\\ 
v\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}$, $K$ is the intrinsic matrix: $\begin{bmatrix}
35 & 0 & 810\\ 
0 & 35  & 540 \\ 
0 & 0 &  1
\end{bmatrix}$ as the focal length of my *ideal* pinhole camera is $35mm$ and the image size is $1620px$ by $1080px$.

My camera is looking straight in the middle of the object and therefore has a translation vector $C=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0  & -distance
\end{pmatrix}$ and $R = I_{3}$.
[image]

My first question is, if I know the width of the world the camera is capturing, which would be e.g. $200mm$ can I use the formula mentioned [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12434/how-do-i-calculate-the-distance-of-an-object-in-a-photo#comment19478_12434), to receive the missing measurements (distance and width of world)?

[image]

After obtaining the distance of the camera to the object I can complete $C=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0  & -448.72mm
\end{pmatrix}$ and should be able to calculate $x = P*X$, so $\begin{pmatrix}
363463.2 & 242308.8  & 448.72
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
35 & 0 & 810 & 363463\\ 
0 &35  & 540 &242308 \\ 
0 &0  &1  & 448.72
\end{bmatrix} * \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0  & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ which correctly gives me the center of the image plane if I divide the first two rows of $x$ by the last.

BUT, now I wanted to project the top left corner of the world which would be $\begin{pmatrix}
-294.87 / 2 & 200 / 2  & 0
\end{pmatrix}$.
[image]
This should give me $\begin{pmatrix}
0  & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ as the image coordinates as the coordinate system starts in the top left corner. But unfortunately it does not. What am I doing wrong.